# dropbox showing "Downloading X files..." for ever

Tags: linux, sync, dropbox

I have dropbox `52.4.58` installed on a Linux VM (Lubuntu 18.04 LTS). The dropbox instance can never finish syncing my folder and reach the `Up to date` status as a Windows version does on the same folder. Instead, the icon on Linux status bar always shows a busy status, and when hovering the mouse over it, it says:

> Downloading 9 files...

for days. .

Currently, the folder does not seem to be in sync on my Windows and Linux machines. I have to stop and resume sync on the Linux instance to keep the folder synchronized. (The windows version works fine, and synchronize changes in minutes.) If I do so, dropbox (Linux) will restart indexing all files, and the changes will be pushed to other machines.

I also found a similar issue reported [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/Windows-7-Dropbox-quot-Downloading-X-files-Y-KB-sec-Z-min-left/td-p/93231).

Is it possible to show the `9 files` that are being downloaded?

(If it's the same files causing the problem, I hope I can identify them and delete them. I'm familiar with python and linux shell. Any suggestions there are welcome.)

-- **Update** --

I did a shell query (as follows) for all file status as suggested in the comments, filtering out files that are `up to date` or `unwatched`. But the query returns nothing, meaning the files are either `up to date` or `unwatched`. Any further suggestions?

```
$ find /file/Dropbox -type f -exec dropbox filestatus {} \; | grep -v 'up to date' | grep -v 'unwatched'
```

Comment: Is it possible that some of your synced folders are symlinks?

Comment: @harrymc The dropbox folder is a mounted NTFS drive. Otherwise, I don't think there are any symlinks because the dropbox folder is created and used in Windows up to this point.

Comment: This command once used to work : `find ~/Dropbox -type f -exec dropbox filestatus {} \; | grep 'syncing'`.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! This is what I'm looking for. Testing it now.

Comment: @harrymc I tried the grep, but it didn't find anything. please see my update.

Comment: So `dropbox filestatus` is not helpful any more. What about just listing all the files on Linux and diffing with the complete list on Windows? The difference should be exactly these 9 files.

Comment: @harrymc Finally, I just verified that your comments are correct. If you make them an answer, I'll accept it. The `find ...` command without `-type f` eventually identified the cause. It's some directories with long names (~ 180 char), which NTFS cannot handle. After deleting those in dropbox, it's in sync again. Thanks

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropbox sub-command to use for checking the status of all dropbox files and
directories is `filestatus`, defined in the
[dropbox man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dropbox.1.html)
as :

> **dropbox filestatus [-l] [-a] [FILE]...**
>
> ```
>   Prints the current status of each FILE.
>
>   options:
>     -l --list  prints out information in a format similar to ls. works best when your console supports color :)
>     -a --all   do not ignore entries starting with .
>
>     Aliases: stat
> ```

Under Linux, you may use it in the following way :

```
find ~/Dropbox -exec dropbox filestatus {} \; | grep 'syncing'
```

The folders and files listed by this command are the ones that cannot
be synced to the target operating system.

For the poster, the problem was with
directories that had very long names (about 180 characters),
which apparently the Windows implementation of dropbox could not handle.

This is the result of a faulty implementation, as the Windows article
[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file)
defines the real limitation :

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an extended-length path, use the "\?\" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very long path".

You should perhaps post a bug-report with dropbox.